# RedirectToAction appends route to URL instead of directing to action in other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have a simple `RedirectToAction` at the end of a controller method in the controller "AccountController". I want to redirect now to a method called `loads` in the `Home` controller. Code:

```
return RedirectToAction("loads", "Home", new { unique_id = new_questionnaire.Unique_ID, purpose = "resume" });
```

Instead of going to `http://localhost:40829/Home/loads/...`, it goes to `http://localhost:40829/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2floads%3funique_id%3d49557%26purpose%3dresume&unique_id=49557&purpose=resume`. What am I doing wrong here? How can I redirect to another controller method while passing route values as well?

Comment: It is possible, if you have `[Authorize]` attribute on your `loads` method, and you are checking manually whether user is authorized or not, and inside that method returning `Redirect(returnUrl)` or in base controller or something. Only by this code part it's not so easy to tell what is going on.

Comment: I removed the `[Authorize]` attribute and the issue persists. The `loads` method only returns views.

Comment: `http://localhost:40829/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2floads%3funique_id%3d309653%26purpose%3dresume&unique_id=309653&purpose=resume` yes, apart from the ids which is by design. it also appends it twice, for some reason.

Comment: it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/altF5hP.jpg

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple redirects there. Your above code doesn't appear to be _completely_ causing what you say it is causing. There are multiple steps involved. We won't be able to help further without a [mcve] of all of the redirects involved.

Comment: A complete example is tough to do with .NET MVC. But stepping through the code I found that it does actually go into the correct controller, but it goes immediately to the first method in the code. This then causes a second redirect, which just returns a view. Strange... The method is called `Index` and it is in the `Home` controller. Btw, if you know a good resource for lerning about proper routing, I'd be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: My suggestion is to provide a [mcve]. General principles with routing are unlikely to be useful to you - particularly once authenticated routes and your custom code are involved. I spent 4 hours on a similar issue yesterday. My advice is 'start debugging'. :P

Comment: @mjwills The problem was that the user was not authenticated when accessing the URL. I am working on an existing webapp and I was told to add a few user roles, such as "unauthenticated" access. I solved it by "authenticating" unregistered users in a way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use Forms Authentication and the user was *not authenticated* when trying to access the URL. This caused the website to redirect the user to the login page.

When `ReturnURL` shows up in the url, this might be the problem. Hope this can help people in the future.

In my case, adding a `Cookie` and a `Forms Authentication Ticket` solved the problem. I already had a function ready for this, I just needed to call it.

Comment: Whenever you see `ReturnUrl` it is **almost always** due to an authenticated route being accessed by an unauthenticated browser.